# How to set interrupts based on inputs

Tags: time, interrupt, avr

I'm going to write a code with three cases(PINA first three ports as inputs and PORTB as outputs), One, toggle all led's connected to PORTB simultaneously with a period T1 when PINA.0 has went HIGH,Second toggle all led's one after one with a period T2... when PINA.1 went HIGH...
The problem is when ever an another input has went high the process should be stopped and switched to the corresponding input, can I use timers and interrupts for this goal?

Comment: Do you mean `PINA first threee pins`, right?

Answer (score 0):

> ... can I use timers and interrupts for this goal?

Answer is YES :)